# json.parse unexpected token error

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

I'm trying to parse string to json object but i always get the same error
SyntaxError: unexpected token '

```
var data = ('{' + fields.productName.toString() + ":" + parseInt(fields.quantity.toString()) + '}' );
```

I tried few variation of this but nothing works.

Comment: What is the value of fields.productName and fields.quantity?

Comment: Do not generate JSON manually, especially when you don't know the JSON syntax. Create an object and leave the stringification to `JSON.stringify`.

Comment: It's strings i get from a form

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best way to avoid issues :

```
  var data = {};
  data[fields.productName.toString()] = parseInt(fields.quantity.toString());
```

P.S. Leverage the beauty of JS objects, Do not re-invent the wheel by constructing object using strings :)

Comment: i'm getting 
[Object Object]
SyntaxError: Unexpected token o

Comment: Are you trying to do alert()? If so, Always remember to stringify JS objects.

Answer (score 2):

You need to have quotes around the value name

```
data = ('{\"' + fields.productName.toString() + "\":" + parseInt(fields.quantity.toString()) + '}' );
```

But you should not generate json manually, because now you would need to escape all quotes that fields.productName.toString() includes. You should use [JSON.stringify](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) instead.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you need that, just do this:

```
var fields = {productName: 'hello', quantity: 1};
var data = {};
data[fields.productName.toString()] = parseInt(fields.quantity.toString());
console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/euxuf9wp/)